# IIS - Unable to access url by ip address instead of localhost

Tags: c#, ip, localhost, vpn, iis-8

I'm trying to publish and test a C# application deployed on a Windows server (with IIS 8.5 installed). Server is whithin a VPN and has an internal IP address. I want to be able to access my application (executable) from internet browser. Currently it is only working when I specify localhost and 127.0.0.1. 
I want to be able to specify server's internal IP address.

localhost:7777/param1=XXX&param2=XXX <-- **Working**
127.0.0.1:7777/param1=XXX&param2=XXX <-- **Working**
172.XX.XX.215:7777/param1=XXX&param2=XXX <-- **Not Working** (Internal IP Address)

Do you have any ideas what can be wrong?

Expected outcome (what I mean by Working):
You launch IIS server
You launch executable
You enter URL in browser
Output is displayed on Application console

Comment: What bindings do you have set up for your web app? Is the firewall allowing external connections?

Comment: It must be firewall issue. Try to telnet that IP and port and see if it is open or filtered.

Comment: @DavidG: yes the firewall is allowing external connections (from whithin VPN). tested from linux server (in VPN) sending telnet or curl to Windows server. I get HTTP 200 Ok.

Comment: @DavidG In latest attempt, there is no more binding. Actually no more web app configured on IIS. Application is configured in a such a way that when launched (executable is running). It listens to specific port. And treats requests accordingly

Comment: @pantonis Please note that even whithin the same server. Browser will work/execute application when I specify localhost but not when I specify IP address by which the server is known whithin VPN

Comment: Hang on, how are you running this app? It doesn't seem like it has anything to do with IIS. Are you self-hosting?

Comment: @DavidG. First and foremost, I am not familiar with IIS (more familiar with Apache Web server). So feel free to give inputs you'd feel necesary. But yes, it is not necesary to configure any site on IIS for application to be launched. It is a webservice. That is self-hosted. Installed on Windows Server. But how it's tricky is that when IIS is turned off. Browser will not be able to access URL. But it will when IIS service is turned on. (but in both cases, there is no site, and no binding to Application location)

Comment: I'm not really too familiar with self hosting unfortunately, but it does sound like you're only listening on the local IP address and not the public one.

Comment: I'm not really too familiar with self hosting unfortunately, but it does sound like you're only listening on the local IP address and not the public one.

Comment: @Alassane Ah that makes sense. Please post your code where you initialize the Http service. You probably need some changes there.

Comment: Hi @DavidG. No problem. Appreciates the feedback though. It helped confirmed some of the assumptions

Comment: Thanks for the hint @pantonis. Code will be definitly reviewed. And I'll sure share some code if resolution is not found in next couple of days.

Comment: Hi Guys. Just wanted to close this topic as it was confirmed that service was only listening to local Ip. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Service was only listening to local Ip.